# Convert network/igraph object to plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have build a network and created both igraph and network object. I can plot the object with ggplot and export to plot_ly using ggplotly.

The problem is that i don´t have real control over the graph so i was wondering if there is a better way to import my network (or Ig graph) into plotly to have better control over the layout.

For example when connecting two nodes i have a weight score and would like to add a slider to filter according to the weight score (between 0 and 1).

I guess plotly could be a nice alternative that would allow dynamic filtering over the network graph.

So here is a reproducible exemple.

I create a bipartite network as follows:

```
library(ggnet)
library(plotly)
library(network)
n <- data.frame(event1 = c(-0.2,0.8,0.4,0),
                event2 = c(0.34,-0.17,0.3,0),
                event3 = c(0.2,0.1,-0.73,0),
                row.names = letters[1:4])
net <- network(n,
               matrix.type = "bipartite",
               ignore.eval = FALSE,
               names.eval = "weights")

col = c("actor" = "grey", "event" = "gold")
set.edge.attribute(net, "color", ifelse(net %e% "weights" > 0, "green", "red"))
g <- ggnet2(net, color = "mode", palette = col, label = TRUE, edge.color = "color",edge.label="weights")
```

[image]
Thanks,

I convert the plot to ggplot format:

```
gp <- ggplotly(g)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(gp), "ggplot.html")
```

I get the following graph.

[image]

How can i add a slider to the graph so i can filter out (dynamically) the edges above or nelow a certain value ???

For example to see all edges >0 ??? I know how do it from the graph itself but it is not dynamic. I want to use plotly to view and use a slider bar to remove edges.

Thanks,

Comment: A reproducible example would help. Including expectations...

Comment: I have updated the question with a reproducible example.

Comment: Does not work: `network::set.edge.attribute(net, "color", ifelse(net %e% "weights" > 0, "green", "red"))` throws `Error in net %e% "weights" : could not find function "%e%"`

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the libraries at the beginning. Added ggnet and plotly libraries.

Comment: Still not reproducible: `Error in network(...) : could not find function "network"`.

Comment: Added the library(network).

Comment: I guess you need something like [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42877610/5784831)?

Comment: Any link with demo data for networks ???

Comment: What I see, filtering is not possible within network. Thus you need to wrap something around where you can filter. E.g. Shiny...